# Residue of $\frac{z^{3/4}}{z^2 + z + 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The poles of $f$ are simple and are $z = e^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}}, e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{3}}$.

So
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,e^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}}) = \lim_{z\rightarrow e^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}}} \frac{z^{3/4}}{z^2 + z + 1} (z-e^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}}) \\= \lim_{z\rightarrow e^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}}} \frac{z^{3/4}}{z-e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{3}}} \\ = \frac{(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})^{3/4}}{2i\Im(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})} \\ = \frac{1^{1/4}}{i\sqrt{3}} \\ = \frac{1}{i\sqrt{3}}.$$

Is this correct? W|A says a completely different answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue+of+z%5E(3%2F4)%2F(z%5E2+%2B+z+%2B+1)

Comment: You simplified $\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3})^{3/4}$ to 1, it should be $i$.

Comment: Ah right, I mindlessly distributed the cube in.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't the value of $\mathrm{exp}(\frac{2\pi i}{3})^{3/4}$ depend on our branch? So if I chose the $arg()$ function to be defined as $-\frac{7\pi}{4} \leq arg(z) \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$, then $\mathrm{exp}(\frac{2\pi i}{3})^{3/4} =  -1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine, but note that $z^{3/4}$ is ambiguous. In particular, it seems to obvious to you that $1^{1/4}$ is one. But it can also be $-1$, $i$, and $-i$. So, it's not amazing that Wolphram Alpha provides a different answer.

Comment: Right, so $1^{3/4}$ really has a different value depending on what branch cut I take for our argument?  
$$z^{1/n} = e^{1/n (\log |z| + iarg(z))}$$  
Consequently, does the integral value change depending on what branch cut I take for the argument? (since residues will change)

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Yes. The statement, as it is, is ambiguous.