# Solving $\mathrm{exp}(z^2) = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Solve $\mathrm{exp}(z^2) = 1$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

This is what I did, however, testing values shows that it's incorrect.

$$\begin{align}\mathrm{exp}(z^2) &= 1 \\ \mathrm{Log}(\mathrm{exp}(z^2)) &= \mathrm{Log}(1) + 2k\pi i \qquad \text{where Log is the principal logarithm, k$\in\mathbb{Z}$} \\ z^2 &= 2k\pi i \\ \mathrm{exp}(2\mathrm{Log}(z)) &= 2k\pi i \\ 2\mathrm{Log}(z) &= \mathrm{Log}(2k\pi i ) + 2n\pi i, \qquad \text{n$\in\mathbb{Z}$} \\ 2\mathrm{Log}(z)&=\ln(|2k\pi|) + 2n\pi i \\ \mathrm{Log}(z) &= \frac{1}{2}\ln(|2k\pi|) + n\pi i \\ z&= \sqrt{|2k\pi|} (-1)^n \end{align}$$

However, testing for $k=3,n=5$, the expression equals $\exp(6\pi)\neq 1$...

Comment: When you have $z^2 = 2k\pi i$, why not take square roots?

Comment: You are missing a $\pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}i$ when you take $\mathrm{Log}(2k\pi i)$.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought the argument of $2k\pi i$ was $0$...  
  
Also, I didn't take square roots because I thought that taking square roots is ambiguous, so I used the definition of $w^{2} = \exp(2\mathrm{Log}(w))$ to make sure I don't miss any solutions. Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: $e^{z^2}=1\implies z^2=i2n\pi\implies z=\pm e^{i\pi/4} \sqrt{2n\pi}$

Comment: Also, should it be $(-1)^k \frac{\pi}{2} i$ instead? (I think it doesn't mke a difference though)

Comment: @MarkViola Can we just use $(e^{i\pi/2})^{1/2} = e^{i\pi/4}$ because the arguments are inside $(-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: What arguments?

Comment: The exponents. Since $\pi/2 \in (-\pi,\pi]$ and $\pi/4 \in (-\pi,\pi]$.  
Iirc, I was doing a question where I had to compute: $(e^{i5/3})^{3/4})$ or something like that, and I can't just say that it equals $(e^{(i5/4)})$

Comment: Oh here it is: I simplified $\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3})^{3/4}$ to be $\exp(2\pi i)^{1/4} = 1$, but this wasn't allowed.  
It was in the top comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447304/residue-of-fracz3-4z2-z-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual mistake I see is your evaluation of the logarithm of $2k\pi i$, which is missing the $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}i$, covering the cases where $k$ is positive or negative (ignoring $0$).

But once you have $z^2 = 2k\pi i$ you need only know how to take square roots of $\pm i$ to finish.  The four roots of $\pm i$ 
are $\pm \frac1{\sqrt 2}\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2}i$, so you have those multiplied with $\sqrt{2k\pi}$ with $k$ a *nonnegative* integer.

Square roots are ambiguous in the sense that $\sqrt{a}$ in general has two values, but solving the equation $z^2 = a$ means finding both square roots of the complex number $a$.  The polar form of the number makes it easier to do so in general.